# UITableView crashes when number of rows >1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have a uitableview that crashes when row is greater than one.  It makes no sense at all since their are two objects in the array.  It works perfectly for object one, but not two.  Check it out:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"rigth not %i", [pro.matches count]);

    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // configure your cell here...
    if ([pro.matches count] >0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [pro.matches objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return cell;
}
```

error:  thread 1 sigabort on when i call [self.tableview reload data];

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13dc022 0x156dcd6 0x13c8644 0x44cea5 0x2591a8 0x204688 0x206862 0xb466d 0xb4167 0x2a42 0x9a5f 0xa2755e 0x96463e 0x95d1e7 0x95ceea 0x9ed0ad 0x3da2330 0x3da4509 0x1313803 0x1312d84 0x1312c9b 0x12c57d8 0x12c588a 0x26626 0x20ed 0x2055)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Where does it crash? What is the crash report?

Comment: You said in your post that it crashes when you reload the tableView. First of all it is [self.tableView reloadData] and not [self.tableview reload data]. Also, can you paste where you are calling reloadData method.

Answer (score 2):

Your app crashes because in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`

you return only 1. You must return `[pro.matches count]`

Comment: when i do that it crashes too

Comment: some more changes are need to do. see answr

Answer (score 2):

In your **if([pro.matches count] > 0)** statement you access **objectAtIndex:1** - if the matches array contains 1 object, it has the index 0, accessing index 1 will crash your app.

Answer (score 1):

use 
`return [pro.matches count]`

instead of return 1 in your number of rows method

Answer (score 1):

Return the array size here:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [pro.matches count];
}
```

Remove the `if` statement and replace it with just:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [pro.matches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

`indexPath.row` is the current row index, starting at zero.

Comment: Then there is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked whether the string in your array is created and initialized correctly? I think there are a few places you need to check:

1. Make sure your array is good and neither the array nor the object inside the array has been deallocated when you reference them.
2. in your -numberOfRowsInSection, it should be 
   return [pro.matches count]
3. in your -cellForRowAtIndexPath, it should be 
   cell.textLabel.text = [pro.matches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

I wrote a demo program, try it out, you will get it. I created a single view app, in the viewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray *list;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *list;
@end
```

and in viewController.m,

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize list;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b", nil];
    self.list = tempArray;
    [tempArray release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

/********************************************************************************
 ******************** UITableViewDataSource Protocol Methods ********************
 ********************************************************************************/

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Protocol Functions

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // configure your cell here...
    if ([list count] >0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return list.count;
}

/********************************************************************************
 ******************** UITableViewDelegate Protocol Methods **********************
 ********************************************************************************/

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Protocol Functions

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}
@end
```

Comment: why is is [pro.matches count-1] and not just [pro.matches object at index: index path.row?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13dc022 0x156dcd6 0x13c8644 0x44cea5 0x2591a8 0x204688 0x206862 0xb466d 0xb4167 0x2a42 0x9a5f 0xa2755e 0x96463e 0x95d1e7 0x95ceea 0x9ed0ad 0x3da2330 0x3da4509 0x1313803 0x1312d84 0x1312c9b 0x12c57d8 0x12c588a 0x26626 0x20ed 0x2055)
terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: thanx michaela! when there is two objects in array can you check in nslog whether two objects are there in your array or not... since you does not put all code that's ahy i'm asking?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, not [pro.matches count-1] but [pro.matches object at index: index path.row]. Try the demo, don't forget in your interface builder, set the datasource and delegate of the uitableview to be the file's owner.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"rigth not %i", [pro.matches count]);

    return  [pro.matches count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // configure your cell here...
    if ([pro.matches count] >0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [pro.matches objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    }
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return cell;
}
```

If it still crashes then post all your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out?  I was having the same problem, and I ended up solving it with the solution posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096988/810360

In short, I just set my table from static to dynamic:

[image: UITableView Properties]